# Better way than if foo.blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement

I am building a basic app that will retrieve a customers data and show it on screen, however some of the fields will be null and so I get a lot of `undefined method 'registration_number' for nil:NilClass` errors

Is there a better way to to deal with these other than lots of if statements

```
if  @customer.registration_number.blank?
Do something
else
@customer.registration_number
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to actually *do* something on missing values, you can't avoid a conditional per value. (Especially if that "something" differs from value to value).

If you want to simply ignore missing values, you can use one of the nil-swallowing tricks.

```
@customer.try(:registration_number)
@customer&.registration_number
@customer.registration_number rescue nil # don't use this one, there are better ways
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a try there

```
@customer.try(:registration_number)
```

and if there is no value, it will just return nil